# web server vs deployment server

Tags: tomcat, deployment, webserver, websphere

I encountered one question recently about the differences between a web server and a deployment server.

With my understanding and what I found on Google,

Web server:

A Web server handles the HTTP protocol. When the Web server receives an HTTP request, it responds with an HTTP response, such as sending back an HTML page
ex Tomcat

But then I tried to look every where for definition of a deployment server and I could only find information about application servers

I know that an application server serves business logic to application programs through any number of protocols, ex WAS

But I was not able to find anything clear on deployment servers.

So, basically I am confused about the following things.

1. Are deployment servers and application servers the same?
2. If a deployment server is different from a web server and an application server, then what is a deployment server, and how is it related to or different from a web server and an application server?

I will really appreciate some responses, as I have tried a lot and could only find everything about web servers and application servers. But I have a clear idea on what a deployment server is.

Comment: Where do you find the term "deployment server"?  Some additional context would be useful for providing an answer.

Comment: @BrettKail - I was asked this during an interview and I was also not sure , If there is any such term and I tried to google it and was not able to find anything on that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such separate thing like `Deployment server`, some may say that deployment server is server where you deploy your application. So it might be web server if your application is bunch of html pages, javascript, cgi or some other scripting language; it might be a application server if you deploy for example Java application in a WAR/EAR form.

PS. And Tomcat is not a web server, but web container (kind of limited application server). Apache is a web server.